# AWS CDK - Can I Pass LambdaInvoke's InputPath Prop Multiple JSON Paths?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I find `new LambdaInvoke` requires the `inputPath` to be a string, so whether I need to pass the `event` an `object` from multiple places, I need a `Pass` state to make it happen.

```js
    this.organiseTheArrayAndId = new Pass(this, "Organise the Array and Id Together In One Object", {
      parameters: {
        "array": JsonPath.stringAt("$.productIdsArray"),
        "value": JsonPath.numberAt("$.productId.id")
      },
      resultPath: "$.organiseTheArrayAndId",
    });

    this.augmentProductIdArray = new LambdaInvoke(this, "Add the Product ID To The Array", {
      lambdaFunction: lambdaFunctionLocation,
      inputPath: "$.organiseTheArrayAndId",
    });
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LambdaInvoke` task construct's [payload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions_tasks.LambdaInvoke.html#payload) property lets you customize the input your function receives when invoked:

```js
payload: sfn.TaskInput.fromObject({
    array: JsonPath.stringAt("$.productIdsArray"),
    value: JsonPath.numberAt("$.productId.id")
}),
```